# How to write this statement symbolically?

Tags: logic

Let's say that I have to write this statement :

> $\tan(-x)$ is equal to $(-\tan x)$ which is not equal to $\tan x$

How do I write this symbolically in one statement?

What about : $\Big (\tan (-x)=(-\tan x) \Big ) \neq \tan x$ ?

Thanks

Comment: or $\tan(-x)=-\tan( x)\ne\tan x$

Comment: You don’t need most of the parentheses: $$\tan(-x)=-\tan x\ne\tan x$$ is fine.

Comment: Actually with those brackets the statement is incorrect. On the LHS you have an equation, on the RHS you have a function.

Comment: Got it, thanks everybody

Comment: @Crostul And, if I have a statement which states that $-\tan x$ is not equal to $\tan x$ which is equal to $\tan (\pi + x)$, how do I write it?

Comment: The same way? $-\tan x \neq \tan x = \tan (\pi + x)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct and proper way to write this is

$$\tan(-x) = - \tan x \text{ and } {- \tan x} \ne \tan x.$$

Or, if you really want to write it using *only* symbols, it's also completely correct to write it as

$$\tan(-x) = - \tan x \quad \land \quad {- \tan x} \ne \tan x.$$

If you want to abbreviate this, it's also acceptable to write it as

$$\tan(-x) = - \tan x \ne \tan x.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! ${}$